# cowplot::plot_grid with facet_wrap - y axis title overlaps axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I am using R and gglot only for a short time, so I am very grateful for any help!
Since I like to use the secondary y-axis to display my mean values with breaks, facet_wrap has become only limitedly suitable to display the three plots side by side. So I used the library "cowplot" to manage that.

[image: 3 Plots side by side with cowplot]

In order to keep the gray heading field - as in other graphs - I applied a facet_wrap to the single graph after all. But the y-axis label moves over the y-ticks label. Neither via margin, nor border or otherwise I manage to push the y-axis label to the outside.

Here is an example code:

```
set.seed(42)  ## for sake of reproducibility
n <- 6
dat_A <- data.frame(id=1:n, 
                  date=seq.Date(as.Date("2020-12-26"), as.Date("2020-12-31"), "day"),
                  group=rep(LETTERS[1:1], n/2),
                  age=sample(18:30, n, replace=TRUE),
                  type=factor(paste("type", 1:n)),
                  x=rnorm(n))

dat_B <- data.frame(id=1:n, 
                    date=seq.Date(as.Date("2020-12-26"), as.Date("2020-12-31"), "day"),
                    group=rep(LETTERS[2:2], n/2),
                    age=sample(18:30, n, replace=TRUE),
                    type=factor(paste("type", 1:n)),
                    x=rnorm(n))

p1 <- ggplot(dat_A, aes(x=x, y=age, fill=group))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = age), linetype = "dashed")+
  geom_jitter(alpha = .4)+
  facet_wrap(~group, scales = "free")+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(10, 30), expand = expansion(mult = c(.05, .05)), sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ., labels = scales::number_format(accuracy = 0.1), breaks = dat_A$age))+
  
  guides(fill=FALSE)+
  theme_bw(base_size = 9)+

labs(
  y = expression(~bold(age)~'in a'),
  color = NULL)+
theme(
  text = element_text(family="Arial", size=9),
  plot.margin = unit(c(0,.7,0,0), "cm"), # c(top, right, bottom, left)
  axis.title.x = element_blank(),
  legend.position = "none"
  )

p2 <- ggplot()+
  geom_point(aes(x, age), dat_B)+
  facet_wrap(~group, scales = "free")+
  labs(
    y = expression(~bold(age)~'in a'),
    color = NULL)+
  theme(
    plot.margin = unit(c(0,.7,0,0), "cm"), # c(top, right, bottom, left)
    axis.line.x = element_blank()
  )

library(cowplot)
plot_grid(p1, p2, p1, align = "h", nrow = 1, ncol = 3, rel_widths = c(22/100, 39/100, 39/100),
          labels = c("A", "B", "C"),
          label_size = 9,
          label_fontfamily = "Cambria", ## emf seems to overwrite "fontfamily"
          label_fontface = "bold",
          label_colour = NULL,
          label_x = -0.03,
          label_y = 1 #0.05
)
```

Maybe interesting for some, otherwise the question can be deleted. For me it is solved.

Thanks
Malte

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you wonder why you haven't got a response yet, please kindly read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi Tjebo, thanks for the hints. While making up a code for the forum, step by step, I found out which line is crushing the y-axis label for me.

If I have 'text = element_text(family="Arial")' in the theme and 'label_fontfamily = "Cambria"' under 'plot_grid', the label is crushed.

Comment: Great! This is also what trying to make it reproducible about - this very very often leads to yourself finding the bug :) In this case, I am not sure what you mean and I cannot really reproduce it on my machine, but fonts are a weird one. I am not sure what you mean with secondary y-axis, I don't really see one... Maybe have a look at the `patchwork` package, I prefer its syntax

Comment: regarding deleting your question - please don't! The hope is that it will actually help someone else in the future. Ideally post your solution as an answer and accept it!